# rebroadcast unconfirmed transaction

Tags: transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions

Idid a transaction one week back with 1 sat/vbyte. Still not confirmed. How can I rebroadcast it from core wallet because some nodes are purging low fee transactions.

Comment: I deleted mempool.dat and did CPFP for stuck transaction after restarting core and it's worked

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Core will automatically rebroadcast transactions for you periodically. Rebroadcasting occurs randomly between 12 and 24 hours from the previous rebroadcast or wallet startup.

To manually rebroadcast, you will need to get the raw transaction and resend it using `sendrawtransaction`. You can get the raw transaction by right clicking the transaction in the transactions list and choosing "Copy raw transaction". Then open the debug console via Window > Console and enter `sendrawtransaction <tx>` where `<tx>` is replaced with the copied raw transaction.

Comment: Hi, Andrew thanks for you answer, the stuck transactions are related to Inscription so would it be safe to follow your steps, and if i rebroadcast following your steps will it get confirmed

Answer (score 0):

I deleted mempool.dat and did CPFP for stuck transaction after restarting core and it's worked, thanks to '/dev/fd0'